# jQuery to get innerHTML not working on a HTMLFontElement object

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, alert, dom-manipulation

I have jQuery to select all `font` elements that are children of the element with `id="right"` within the html stored in the var `html`... when I do an alert to see how many elements it gets:

```
alert($("#right > font", html).length);
```

it gives me an alert of: `5`

but when I try any of the following, I don't get any alerts...

```
alert($("#right > font", html)[0].html());
alert($("#right > font", html)[0].text());
alert($("#right > font", html)[0].val());
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the element is not an instance of jQuery, and its just a DOM object you can't use any of the jQuery methods. You can use innerHTML to get the result.

```
alert($("#right > font", html)[0].innerHTML);
```

If you want to apply any of the jQuery methods to the element you have to make it a jquery object like

```
alert($($("#right > font", html)[0]).html());
```

or

```
$("#right > font").each(function(){
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

Comment: Just to elaborate a little: When you access the numbered properties of a jQuery object, you get the original DOM objects and not jQuery objects.